# Unable to execute binary file Linux - No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have an executable `launcher-x64-linux`, that when invoking `./launcher-x64-linux` spits out "bash: ./launcher-x64-linux: No such file or directory"

Invoking `file launcher-x64-linux` gives me:

> launcher-x64-linux: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=4ec13ff8901e49db678f8c4ba00bb6da52ef55b3, stripped

Invoking `uname -m` spits out x86_64 and `readelf launcher-x64-linux | grep interpreter` locates the program interpreter at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

and `getconf LONGBIT` returns 64

So I know it's not a mismatch between 32/64-bit binary and OS

Invoking `ldd launcher-x64-linux` tells me:

- libpthread.so.0
- libdl.so.2
- libstdc++.so.6
- libm.so.6
- libgcc_s.so.1
- libc.so.6
- ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
  which I would presume means I'm not missing any libraries

Am I missing something? I'm perplexed as to why I'm told "no such file or directory" exists when I try executing it. Thank you

Comment: `strace -ff -e trace=open,openat sh -c ./launcher-x64-linux` might provide some useful information

Comment: Does `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` exist?

Comment: I think a more normal place for that would be something like `/usr/lib/lib64`

Comment: @Barmar No, /lib64 is a perfectly normal place on some systems, e.g. Arch Linux.

Comment: @ypnos Hmm, so maybe the executable was compiled for Arch Linux,but they're trying to run it on something else.

Comment: Nah, I'm pretty sure the interpreter that `file` gives here is the one on the system that would run the executable file in question.

Comment: @ypnos The `file` output is from the ELF header, and this path needs to exist on the current system. If it doesn't, you get the symptoms OP describes. My Debian system also uses this path.

Comment: Did you forget `chmod +x ./launcher-x64-linux`?

Comment: I did set chmod to +x before trying other things

Comment: @thatotherguy Good point. Explanation here https://greek0.net/elf.html

Comment: @Orange Receptacle  can you run it with: sh launcher-x64-linux  ?  can you see it inside function  with: nm -C  launcher-x64-linux  ?

Comment: in  nm -C  launcher-x64-linux   output  , the flags not be 'U"  (undefined)

Comment: nm -C tells me that there are no symbols, and invoking sh prints out "cannot create 5@@8J@8 ..." along with a bunch of other weird characters

Comment: @Orange Receptacle The file may be damaged or not compiled properly , Can this Linux run another executable file properly? If yes, have you re-compiled launcher-x64-linux ? Do you have access to the source  launcher-x64-linux?